# Revit shared coordinates to Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What is the correct process for getting a transform between Forge coordinates and Revit's *shared* coordinates? I know there is globalOffset, but does it reference the Revit project internal coordinate system or shared coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update Jun 11th, 2021**

Now my [MultipleModelUtil.js](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil/blob/master/MultipleModelUtil.js) supports the alignments I shared below. Also, we can easily tell Forge Viewer to use **By [shared coordinates](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Collaborate/files/GUID-B82147D6-7EAB-48AB-B0C3-3B160E2DCD17-htm.html)** to aggregate models. Here is the code snippet, and you can check out [here](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil#supported-alignments) to know supported alignments

```js
const util = new MultipleModelUtil( viewer );

util.options = {
  alignment: MultipleModelAlignmentType.ShareCoordinates
};

const models = [
  { name: '1.rvt', urn: 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLlNpaHgxOTVuUVJDMHIyWXZUSVRuZFE_dmVyc2lvbj0x' },
  { name: '2.rvt', urn: 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLldVRHJ4ajZ6UTBPLTRrbWZrZ3ZoLUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x' },
  { name: '3.rvt', urn: 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjRyZW5HRTNUU25xNHhYaW5xdWtyaWc_dmVyc2lvbj0x' }
];

util.processModels( models );
```

==================

First, Forge Viewer supports 3 kinds of Revit link methods as the below, and you can take a look at the 3rd one (By shared coordinates).

1. **Origin to origin**: Apply the `globalOffset` of the 1st model to others. Check [MultipleModelUtil/MultipleModelUtil.js](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil/blob/master/MultipleModelUtil.js) for the demo
2. **Center to center**: the default way of the viewer.
3. **By [shared coordinates](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Collaborate/files/GUID-B82147D6-7EAB-48AB-B0C3-3B160E2DCD17-htm.html)**: set up applyRefpoint: true and make the `globalOffset` to the `refPoint`. **This method is the one you are looking for.**

The `refPoint` is the Revit survey point location inside Revit internal coordinate system. It's accessible with the [AecModelData](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/mapping-between-sheets-and-3d-views-aec-models). Meanwhile, you can take advantage of the [AggregatedView](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/aggregated-view/) to use this aligning option. Here is an example of telling how to use AggregatedView:
https://gist.github.com/yiskang/c404af571ba4d631b5929c777503891e

If you want to use this logic with the Viewer class directly, here is a code snippet for you:

```js
let globalOffset = null;

const aecModelData = bubbleNode.getAecModelData();
const tf = aecModelData && aecModelData.refPointTransformation; // Matrix4x3 as array[12]
const refPoint = tf ? { x: tf[9], y: tf[10], z: 0.0 } : { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 };

// Check if the current globalOffset is sufficiently close to the refPoint to avoid inaccuracies.
const MaxDistSqr = 4.0e6;
const distSqr    = globalOffset && THREE.Vector3.prototype.distanceToSquared.call(refPoint, globalOffset);
if (!globalOffset || distSqr > MaxDistSqr) {
    globalOffset = new THREE.Vector3().copy(refPoint);
}

viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, bubbleNode, { applyRefpoint: true, globalOffset: globalOffset, keepCurrentModels: true });
```

The `bubbleNode` can be either of the following:

```js
bubbleNode = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()

//Or

const viewables = viewerDocument.getRoot().search({'type':'geometry'});
bubbleNode = viewables[0];
```

To get `AecModelData`, please refer to my gist: https://gist.github.com/yiskang/c404af571ba4d631b5929c777503891e#file-index-html-L67

```js
// Call this line before using AecModelData
await doc.downloadAecModelData();

// doc.downloadAecModelData(() => resolve(doc));
```

See here for details of the AecModelData: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api

Comment: One clarifying question: why is the refPoint Z value 0.0? Should that not match the elevation of the survey point?

Comment: I think the options object should be `{ applyRefpoint: true, globalOffset: globalOffset , keepCurrentModels: true }`  otherwise the variable `globalOffset` would be unused

Comment: Hi @Yasser Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the code snippet. My apologies for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found success feeding the `refPointTransformation` into a matrix4.

This way, the orientation of the model is also taken into account. (This is based off [Eason's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018048/2474359)).

```js
const bubbleNode = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
await doc.downloadAecModelData();
const aecModelData = bubbleNode.getAecModelData();
const tf = aecModelData && aecModelData.refPointTransformation;
const matrix4 = new THREE.Matrix4()
  .makeBasis(
    new THREE.Vector3(tf[0], tf[1], tf[2]),
    new THREE.Vector3(tf[3], tf[4], tf[5]),
    new THREE.Vector3(tf[6], tf[7], tf[8])
  )
  .setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(tf[9], tf[10], tf[11]))

viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables, {
  placementTransform: matrix4,
  keepCurrentModels: true,
  globalOffset: {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "z": 0
  },
  applyRefpoint: true,
  applyScaling: 'ft',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Chang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74872431/13664939) is a good apointment to use revit's shared coordinates, but if have coordinates far from zero i recommend convert coordinates more close to zero to better rendering and avoid problems with then.

```js
Promise.all(
    docs.map(({ urn, name }) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
          `urn:${urn}`,
          async (Document) => {
            Document.downloadAecModelData(() => {
              resolve({
                doc: Document,
                name,
              });
            });
          },
          () => console.error("Failed fetching Forge manifest")
        );
      });
    })).then((docs) => {
    Promise.all(
      docs.map(async ({ doc }) => {
        const bubbleNode = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        const aecModelData = bubbleNode.getAecModelData();
        if (aecModelData) {
          const tf = aecModelData.refPointTransformation;
          return { x: tf[9], y: tf[10], z: tf[11] };
        }
      })
    ).then((refs) => {
      const points = refs.filter((el) => el !== undefined);
      const refPosition = points.reduce(
        (p, c, i, arr) => {
          const div = i + 1 === arr.length ? arr.length : 1;
          return {
            x: (p.x + c.x) / div,
            y: (p.y + c.y) / div,
            z: (p.z + c.z) / div,
          };
        },
        { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
      );
      docs.forEach(async ({ doc, name }) => {
        const bubbleNode = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        const aecModelData = bubbleNode.getAecModelData();
        const tf = aecModelData && aecModelData.refPointTransformation;
        const matrix4 = new THREE.Matrix4()
          .makeBasis(
            new THREE.Vector3(tf[0], tf[1], tf[2]),
            new THREE.Vector3(tf[3], tf[4], tf[5]),
            new THREE.Vector3(tf[6], tf[7], tf[8])
          )
          .setPosition(
            new THREE.Vector3(
              tf[9] - refPosition.x,
              tf[10] - refPosition.y,
              tf[11] - refPosition.z
            )
          );

        viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, bubbleNode, {
          placementTransform: matrix4,
          keepCurrentModels: true,
          globalOffset: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            z: 0,
          },
          applyRefpoint: true,
          applyScaling: "ft",
        });
      });
    });});
```

With this example based on Jonathan's code I used multiple models and load averyone refPointTransformation to use these points like base to drag the models closer to zero, there are some discussions apointing to use globalOffset with position but in cases with big numbers this can cause poor rendering in viewer.