# Autodesk Forge - refPoint info in SQLLite db

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have 3 revit models on BIM360 and I want to view them in a Forge Viewer.
To do this, I aggregated the 3 models with the information provided at this link [Revit shared coordinates to Forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66895484/revit-shared-coordinates-to-forge-viewer/67018048#67018048), and everything is OK.
I want to know if is possibile to get refPoint information in the model's SQLLite db (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer)
Is it possible?

TIA
Alder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `refPoint` data is extracted into AEC Model Data only. It's a JSON file. You can get see it in the model manifest via calling [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) and download it by using [GET {urn}/manifest/{derivativeurn}](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/)

```json
{
    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcH....x/output/Resource/AECModelData.json",
    "role": "Autodesk.AEC.ModelData",
    "mime": "application/json",
    "guid": "a4aac952-a3f4-031c-4113-b2d9ac2d0de6",
    "type": "resource",
    "status": "success"
},
```

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api