# Autodesk Forge - Revit coordinates

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

is it possible to get revit models coordinates with model derivative API?
I mean coordinates that in revit I get with manage -> Location  (see picture)[Revit manage -> location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3sQz.png)

TIA
Alder

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely obtain this information using Forge Design Automation API. I am not sure how to get it in the model derivative API; the information in Eason Kang's answer on [Revit shared coordinates to Forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66895484/revit-shared-coordinates-to-forge-viewer) ought to come in useful, though.